# Table value labels vanish when a "weights" variable is included when using R's sjPlot package

Tags: r

If weights are not used when producing a table, sjPlot delivers as expected, see: [Without Weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK6sL.jpg).  However, if weights are used, weights are applied, but the value labels vanish, see:
[With Weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4DeE.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?
 The above tables can be replicated with the following script (originally included with the sjPlot package. I just added a field, named "MYweights", to the original dataframe in order to illustrate my question)

```
library(sjmisc)
library (sjPlot)
data(efc)
efc.labels <- get_labels(efc)

# print simple cross table with labels
## Not run: 
sjt.xtab(efc$e16sex, efc$e42dep)
# print cross table with manually set
# labels and expected values
sjt.xtab(efc$e16sex, 
         efc$e42dep, 
         variableLabels = c("Elder's gender", 
                            "Elder's dependency"),
         valueLabels = list(efc.labels[['e16sex']], 
                            efc.labels[['e42dep']]),
         showExpected = TRUE)
efc$MYweights <- 1.2
# ## Without weights, value labels appear
sjt.xtab(efc$e16sex, efc$e42dep, 
         showHorizontalLine = FALSE,
         showCellPerc = FALSE,
         highlightTotal = TRUE,
         showSummary=FALSE)
## With weights, value labels vanish
sjt.xtab(efc$e16sex, efc$e42dep, 
         weightBy = efc$MYweights,
         showHorizontalLine = FALSE,
         showCellPerc = FALSE,
         highlightTotal = TRUE,
         ,showSummary=FALSE)
```

Comment: I just saw it's a bug where I forgot to set back value labels after calling `stats::xtabs`. Will fix this the next days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in `sjt.xtab` and is now fixed. If you like to test, you can download the latest [GitHub-build](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel) from the **sjPlot**-package.